# Can I have a single server listen on more than 65535 ports by attaching an IPv4 address

Tags: linux, debian, ssh-tunneling, tcp, tcp-ip

I have a *number* of servers to SSH into, and some of them, being behind different NATs, may require an SSH tunnel. Right now I'm using a single VPS for that purpose. When that *number* reaches [65535 - 1023 = 64512](https://serverfault.com/questions/103626/what-is-the-maximum-port-number), and the VPS runs out of ports to attach tunnels to, do I spin up another VPS, or do I simply attach an additional IP address to the existing VPS?

In other words, is a 65535 limit set per a Linux machine, or per a network interface? [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/251596/is-there-a-hard-limit-of-65536-open-tcp-connections-per-ip-address-on-linux) seems to say it's per an IP address in general, and per IPv4 address specifically. So does a *5-tuple* mean that introducing a new IP address will warrant a new tuple, therefore resetting the limit? And if IPv4 is the case, is it different for IPv6?

Comment: @ilkkachu that's what I read in the [answer linked above](https://superuser.com/questions/251596/is-there-a-hard-limit-of-65536-open-tcp-connections-per-ip-address-on-linux): *A connection consists of 5 pieces of info, in geek speak a 5-tuple. It is determined by protocol (TCP, UDP), local IP address and port, and remote IP address and port*

Comment: @aexl Except that in your case, you don't have to look at the 5-tuple -- you don't have to distinguish between connections, as multiple connections can be created simultaneously on each tunnel. You're rather looking at the 2-tuple defining a tunnel: interface address and listening port on the tunneling machine (other data defining a tunnel is implicit: target address and port of each tunnel are configured as "meta data" of each 2-tuple; protocol is implicitely TCP because you're only interested in SSH connections). If that 2-tuple is exhausted, you need another interface address.

Comment: @aexl, right, the protocol too, of course. The cases referring to 4-tuples probably just think of TCP only.

Comment: While you've got the answers to the question you asked, I'd urge you to explore more strategic options to see if you can change protocols such that you're not trying to deal with ~2^16 simultaneous connections, to something more 'usual'.  That should help with scaling, etc, as you'd find there's more standard documentation/solutions, etc, to be found.

Comment: If it's truly about SSH, have you considered using your VPS as a jump host (i.e., `ssh -J publicvps internal-machine`) instead of port forwarding? That way you can access internal machines without needing non-standard ports.

Comment: This is a good question, but won't help with your overall design and complexity.  Instead you might benefit from VPNs, either a mesh of site-to-site tunnels on ipsec, so that the remote network is routeable, or you may need a client network like OpenVPN so that your own computer has direct routes to things behind the VPS host.   Upshot - time for some network design.

Comment: @GwynEvans I'd love to explore a new approach, but from your message I can't tell what should I be looking into. Can you please hint me with a search query, and I'll take it from there?

Comment: @marcelm please clarify if that will work when the remote machines are all on different networks, i.e. I can't group them under one NAT having one common jump host (unless I set up a VPN, which I probably will somewhere down the road, but not immediately now)

Comment: @aexl Not knowing specifics and without wanting to get into a conversation as that would be too far off-topic for here, it was a general suggestion to see if the underlying requirements could be met in some other form, e.g. having the servers periodically report to a central server, rather than have the VPS connect out to them, as that might scale better.  One example of an alternative framework that _might_ be worth considering would be something like [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/manual/introduction/about), but I could be entirely wrong regarding your requirements!

Comment: It is quite likely you don't want those tunnels to be reachable from the Internet at large, do you? You probably want them associated to either local loopback addresses (127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2...) or private addresses reachable only from you own network.

Comment: Do you truly have *sixty five thousand different machines* that need to be accessed by ssh? By a human? Or is this some sort of automated deployment or configuration system, like `ansible`?

Comment: *VPS runs out of ports to attach tunnels to* - are you expecting more than 65535 **concurrent** connections? A particular port does get re-used if connection formerly using it been closed long enough..

Comment: Agree with others that ssh tunnels are almost certainly the wrong tool for this job.  I recommend WireGuard, which is something you can [configure yourself](https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/) or use something like [tailscale](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-tailscale-works/) to manage it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most certainly can have multiple processes listening on the same port if they are bound to different IPs.

Here's a demonstration using `nc`:

```
% nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 &
[1] 24985
% nc -l 192.168.1.178 1234 &
[2] 24988
% netstat -an | grep 1234
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.178.1234     *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.1234         *.*                    LISTEN
```

As you see, I started `nc` twice in listen mode, one bound to `127.0.0.1`, the other to `192.168.1.178` (which happen to be two of the IP addresses on that computer), both using port `1234`.

`netstat` then shows two listening sockets.

I made the test on macOS, but on Linux you could add `-p` to netstat to show the two distinct processes. On macOS you can use `lsof -nP` to show the same thing.

Note that since you are opening a "hole" in a security layer, you probably don't want to bind to an externally reachable (public) IP address, otherwise anyone can connect to that IP+port and reach the remote system which apparently needed to be protected.

You should use only loopback IP addresses (`127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.2`...) or private IP addresses on a private network reachable only by trusted systems.

For completeness, let's specify that an active TCP connection is defined by a 4-tuple (local IP, local port, remote IP, remote port), but a listening socket is indeed defined only by local IP and port. Connections established to that socket will get the full 4-tuple.

Answer (score 17):

The limit on listening ports is per address regardless of IPv4 or IPv6.  The limitation comes from [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) and [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure) packet headers which are two bytes and so port numbers for TCP and UDP can only be in the rage `0x0000` (0) to `0xFFFF` (65535).

When any service (including an SSH server) listens to a port, it can chose to listen to one IP address or every IP address.  So adding a new address won't necessarily help unless you configure each service to listen to one specific IP address.

However two or more service **can** share the same port as long as they are listening to different IP addresses.

---

To be honest NAT has always been a bit of a hack. The need for it has dropped in IPv6 wich each machine having it's own public facing IPv6 address and a firewall limiting incoming connections to replace the NAT.

---

The more common approach to this situation is is to use a "bastion" machine... users ssh into bastion and from there ssh into the box they want.

Comment: Hi @Philip, thank you for your answer and sorry about the confusion. These clients need to become connectable while staying behind NAT, so each of them gets an SSH tunnel to a special server, and is identified by a tunnel port number rather than an individual IP address. I'm planning for what will happen when/if I run out of the port numbers on that server, with the options being **a).** get a new server or **b).** attach another IP address to the existing server

Comment: @aexl I would assign a pool to the NAT box in this case, rather than the server.

Comment: @PhilipCouling oh yes, good point, I have edited the question, thank you

Comment: @throx thank you for the suggestion. My *servers* (I originally said *clients*, that was incorrect) are on different networks and are behind different NATs. Please clarify, by saying *NAT box* do you mean a single router behind which from reading my question it seemed they all were?

Comment: @PhilipCouling I just read about the [bastion host concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host). Thank you. This is actually a good idea regardless. I can move some common configuration and/or rules to this bastion host where if needed I will be able to reconfigure them just once, without having to repeat on each remote machine. But still, even the bastion host has only so many ports available, and will have to accept tunnels from the remote machines (servers), because they are on different networks, i.e. as far as I know I can't have them all under one common bastion host

Comment: @aexl I think I need a network diagram to understand what you are doing and why it's a problem

Comment: @aexl You can have more than one incoming connection to the same port, if that's what you're worried about. Your SSH server uses port 22 for all SSH connections to it

Comment: @user253751 No there was a mixup between "server" and "client". aexl has many SSH servers behind a single IP and NAT port forwarding to each one.  This requires a port allocating to each server.

Answer (score 7):

Both [IPv4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1) and [IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460#section-3) do not have port concept, only source and destination IP address. The port limit is determined by [TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1) and [UDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768) protocols.

If you want to extend the starting port limit (default: 1024) to add some more ports to end users you can lower the privileged port range to some lower number with `sysctl`:

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=100" > /etc/sysctl.d/privileged_ports.conf
```

You can use IP aliases to add multiple IP addresses to single network interface card.

With systemd you use [`.network`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html) files:

```ini
[Network]
Address=192.168.55.1/24
Address=192.168.55.2/24
Gateway=...
```

Comment: Changing the unprivileged port start to get a few hundred more ports seems pretty unreasonable to me.

Answer (score 4):

The port is assigned to ip address and you can assigne (in Linux as I know) more then one IP address to the interface. But of course there may be other limits (like available file descriptors - socket() system call return file descriptor or -1 wher error).